# How to set different font colours for different textareas

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have two textareas ("comment" and "observation") and I would like to set different font colour for each of these areas (blue for comment and red for observation):

HTML:

Comment:

```
  <div id="Observation">
  <label for="Observation">Observation:</label>
<textarea name="observation" rows="6" style="width: 530px;" id="Obs4.19" placeholder="Enter text of observation here ..."></textarea>
  </div>
```

CSS:

textarea {font-family: Calibri; color:#FF0000; font-size: 14px;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use something that you can use to identify each `textarea` with, like a name or an ID.

```
textarea[name="observation"] { color: red; }
textarea[name="comment"] { color: blue; }
```

Answer (score 1):

give id's to both:

```
#comment {color:red;}

#observation {color:green;}
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/989kg/)

Comment: I can't because I already have an element #observation, which is not a  textarea.